# How to start my program with the discrete display card?

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia

I have written a program using a lot of openGL calls. But When I run the program on Nvidia Optimus system, the integrated display card is always used. That is not what I want. Because some hardware features are missing on integrated display card which use by my program.

**So how to tell the optimus system to use discrete display card when run my program?**

I know the user can choose a particular graphics processor to use by Nvidia Control Panel. But I don't want that operation is done by each user of my program. The switching decision should be done in my program. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks very much.

By the way, how to do this if I have a AMD display card?

Comment: @NicolBolas By the way, how to do this on AMD display card? Do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blogpost about it: [here](http://stevendebock.blogspot.be/2013/07/nvidia-optimus.html)

The blogpost boils down to adding :

```
 extern "C" {  
      _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;  
 }
```

to your code.

Here is a reference to the [NVIDIA documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf).

Comment: By the way, how to do this on AMD display card? Do you know?

Comment: No sorry, no AMD cards here...